# The installed managed class zqu.ProductSelectorController is not visible

Tags: controller-extension, custom, global-variables, global-methods

I am getting this error trying to use a custom visual force page in place of a managed package visual force page.  I made my custom controller global, thinking that it was mine that needed to be declared global, but, I am wondering, is the original managed Zuora class not visible?  I don't think there is any way for me to modify that, but, from what I see on their site, it should be global, can anybody help me, I believe I am getting closer on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller `zqu.ProductSelectorController` is not global, you will not be able to access it from your visualforce page.

If you open the class from Setup->Develop->Apex Classes you should be able to see from the Class Summary tab whether it is Global or not, I would expect you'd see `Class is not defined as global` given the error you get.

If you are writing your own controller or extension, you'd have to completely re-implement the code in `zqu.ProductSelectorController` as neither your page or controller/extension will be able to access methods and properties on it.

Some bedtime reading on Access Modifiers [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) which explains in more detail.

Comment: Thanks Phil, you were correct, the zqu.ProductSelectorController is not global, which seems weird, because it is zuora's managed package component SelectProducts that I am trying to pull into my VF page, and, I followed the instructions on Zuora, and, then I get this error.  I would think they would have made that global.  I will try going through the instructions again anyway, maybe I missed something, but, at least I know why I am getting the error.  Thanks, I will mark this as being answered by you.  Much appreciated.